# Probability of winning once if there are 150 winners in 2000 tickets

Tags: probability

I'm looking to enter a raffle.  The are 150 winning tickets out of the 2000 given.  I want to know my chances of winning at least once if I have 3 and 4 tickets.  The initial answer I got was about 20.86% for 3 tickets, 26.81% for 4 tickets.  Is that right?  I'm sure there might be an easier way, but I just took the odds of me not winning each time assuming I didn't win the time before so 1-((1850/2000)*(1849/1999)*(1848/1998)*(1847/1997)).

Answer (score 0):

Your answers are right, but for heaven's sake, don't call them **odds**, they are **probabilities**

The two are not synonymous

odds = favorable outcomes : unfavorable outcomes

probability = favorable outcomes /total outcomes

*PS*

The other way you could compute them is using combinations, eg for the 3 ticket case,

$$\text {Pr} = 1- \frac{1850\choose 3}{2000\choose 3}$$